# Stuck on how to create DeleteBelow/Above and CountBelow/Above Methods for a NumberList

Tags: c#

Hey guys so im trying to create a NumberList class, that will keep track of a list of any number of floating-point values. Also being able to perform operations on these values using a private list to keep track of the numbers.

Im having trouble on how to create four methods which are:

- void DeleteBelow(float threshold)

This method removes from the list all numbers that are below threshold. If myList is a NumberList containing {1, 2, 3} calling myList.DeleteBelow(1.5) will remove 1, leaving just {2, 3}.

- void DeleteAbove(float threshold)

This method removes from the list all numbers that are above threshold. If myList is a NumberList containing {1, 2, 3} calling myList.DeleteAbove(1.5) will remove 2 and 3, leaving just {1}.

- int CountBelow(float threshold)

This method counts how many numbers in the list are below threshold. If myList is a NumberList containing {1, 2, 3} calling myList.CountBelow(2.5) will return 2.

- int CountAbove(float threshold)

This method counts how many numbers in the list are above threshold. If myList is a NumberList containing {1, 2, 3} calling myList.CountAbove(2.5) will return 1.

I was wondering if someone would be able help me out/point me in the right direction?

~Cheers

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Numbers

{

public class NumberList
{
    // Your private List<float> field should go here
    private List<float> myList;

    public void Add(float number)
    {
        myList.Add(3);
    }

    public List<float> Numbers()
    {
        return myList;
    }
    public float Minimum()
    {
        return myList.Min();
    }
    public float Maximum()
    {
        return myList.Max();
    }
    public float Sum()
    {
        return myList.Sum();
    }
    public float Average()
    {
        return myList.Sum() /myList.Count();
    }
public int Count()
    {
             return myList.Count(); 
    }
public void DeleteBelow(float threshold)
    {
      //       myList.DeleteBelow(1.5) 
    }

public void DeleteAbove(float threshold)
    {
//       myList.DeleteAbove(1.5);
    }
    public int CountBelow(float threshold)
    {
       int CountBelow = 0;
        for (int i = myList.Count is; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (NumberList(i) > threshold) ;
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    public int CountAbove(float threshold)
    {
//      return myList.CountAbove(2.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in the `Add` which always add the number 3 instead of the given one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void DeleteBelow(float threshold)
{
          myList.RemoveAll(x => x < threshold); 
}

public void DeleteAbove(float threshold)
{
          myList.RemoveAll(x => x > threshold); 
}

public int CountBelow(float threshold)
{
     return myList.Count(x => x < threshold);
}

public int CountAbove(float threshold)
{
     return myList.Count(x => x > threshold);
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `myList.RemoveAll(predicate)` instead of a manual loop. Additionally, the remove methods of yours will throw an exception because you're modifying the list while iterating over it, at the very least call `.ToList()` on it and enumerate that, but `RemoveAll` is much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop to loop through all items of the list and then you can check for each element of it is above the threshold. When it is do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would foster you to follow the path of [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). It will make your class easier to maintain because it will preserve you from nasty side-effects (typically in `DeleteBelow` and `DeleteAbove` if you were using `myList.Remove()`). 
I also simplified `Average` since LINQ already has such method available.

```
public sealed class NumberList
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<float> myList;
    public NumberList(IEnumerable<float> numbers) => myList = numbers;
    public NumberList Add(float number) => new NumberList(myList.Concat(new[] { number }));
    public List<float> Numbers() => myList.ToList();
    public float Minimum() => myList.Min();
    public float Maximum() => myList.Max();
    public float Sum() => myList.Sum();
    public float Average() => myList.Average();
    public int Count() => myList.Count();
    public int CountBelow(float threshold) => myList.Count(n => n < threshold);
    public int CountAbove(float threshold) => myList.Count(n => n > threshold);
    public NumberList DeleteBelow(float threshold) => new NumberList(myList.Where(n => n >= threshold));
    public NumberList DeleteAbove(float threshold) => new NumberList(myList.Where(n => n <= threshold));
}
```